# OutOfMemoryError while importing JasperPrint from file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

I am using jasper reports in java (xmx=4096m). I have created a huge report with 200,000 rows from PGSQL database using [`JRGzipVirtualizer`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRGzipVirtualizer.html). In memory the virtualizer takes around 700MB space. Stored the [`JasperPrint`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html) object in a file through `ObjectOutputStream`. It creates a file of 2.9GB.

When I try to read it through `ObjectInputStream` it throws an `OutOfMemoryError`.

My guess is that the gzipvirtualizer is compressing the data so it can reside in memory. But when stored in file it is not compressed. So when reading it tries to read a huge uncompressed data.

can I somehow make it write things compressed OR solve it otherway.

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace? It can help what memory area is related to the error.

Comment: @Lexandro I dont have a stacktrace.... i have linked the heapdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a virtualizer on JasperPrint object deserialization can be done by calling [JRVirtualizationHelper](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVirtualizationHelper.html).[setThreadVirtualizer()](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVirtualizationHelper.html#setThreadVirtualizer) or by using [JRLoader](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.html).[loadJasperPrint()](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.html#loadJasperPrint%28java.io.File,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRVirtualizer%29)

Ref: [Deserializing JasperPrint objects from .jrprint files should allow
    use of JRVirtualizer functionality](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543271/deserializing-jasperprint-object-virtualizer)